# Detect browser and redirect to page in same server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm working on a codeIgniter project with using MVC.

I need to detect Microsoft Internet Explorer (IE) agents and redirect them to another page in my localhost using .htaccess file. Then I tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [6-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/secPay/doc [R]
```

But Unfortunately it does not work and gives error like below:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

But it redirects to another servers like `http://www.nic.lk`

But I need to redirect it to `http://localhost/secPay/doc`

So what can I do? How to solve this?

Comment: Browser specific code is just bad form in this age

Comment: You could use the User Agent Class. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/user_agent.html

Comment: No, I need to do it by using .htaccess file and I need to solve this                      This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS                                                                                  What are the possible ways I can solve this using htacess ?

Comment: How can it redirect to `http://www.nic.lk` if you didn't tell it to? Perhaps a controller is doing that? I also don't understand why you need to do this using `.htaccess` - the `user_agent` library is there for a reason and, so far as I can remember, is pretty good.